# Проверка на тип файла

Tags: delphi

Здравствуйте! Подскажите, как задать проверку файла на его расширение, например .txt?

```
procedure TForm1.Memo1DragDrop(Sender, Source: TObject; X, Y: Integer);
var s:string;
begin
s:=fileListBox1.Items.Strings[fileListBox1.ItemIndex];  
begin
  memo1.Lines.LoadFromFile(s);
  showmessage('Файл успешно перемещен');
end
else
  showmessage('Файл не удалось переместить');
end;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Привет. Попробуй так:

```
if (ExtractFileExt(s) = ".txt") then begin
    showmessage('Расширение файла: txt');
end
```

Comment: На самом деле существует целое семейство процедур выделения ExtractFile***, так, можно выделить путь, имя файла и его раширение.